# CURL - Getting occurencies in HTML source of a Link

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm trying to simply count how much times i can find this string `"SizeName":"6 (XXS)"` in this link's source: http://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-short-running-tights-ladies-457513?colcode=45751359

The string is contained in a Javascript which can be seen in the source of the URL.

Here is the code i'm using but it says that it is finding `0`occurencies:

```
<?PHP
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/karrimor-short-running-tights-ladies-457513?colcode=45751359";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 $str = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl);  

$SIZEID = "6 (XXS)";
$occurencies = preg_match_all('/(?<=\"SizeName\":\"'.$SIZEID.'\")\S+/i', $str, $match);

echo $occurencies;
```

The output result is: `Occurencies: 0`

But in this link when i get the output source i can find 5 matches of string `"SizeName":"6 (XXS)"`

Where is my problem and what i'm doing wrong?

Any advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to escape brackets `(` and `)`?

Comment: What is with all the fancy lookbehind stuff? If you just want a count, that is overkill and likely what is causing your problem.

Comment: @caCtus Yes it seems the problem comes from the `(` `)` but they must be in. Any way i can transform my script to make it work ?

Comment: Escape the `( )` by prefixing them with a backslash - `\\` *How the hell do you use syntax highlighting on a backslash?!*

Comment: Can you give me complete answer with the advised by you fix so i can mark it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm may be missing something, but why use a regex at all?  Why not just split the string, like so:

```
$sizeId = "6 (XXS)";
$delimiter = '"SizeName":"' . $sizeId .'"';
$exploded = explode($delimiter, $str);
$matches = count($exploded) - 1;
```

Disclaimer: I have not written PHP in over 10 years. The above may have syntax errors. :)

Comment: Can you please give me complete change of the code you think i must use otherwise ? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. I updated my example with "real" PHP code. I haven't written PHP in a loooooong time though, so please excuse any typos. :)